# Как получить новые координаты балуна на Яндекс карте?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Пытаюсь сделать приложение, которое после ввода адреса определяет координаты объекта на карте. Затем открывается карта, на которой стоит балун по этим координатам. Его можно передвинуть, если пользователь не согласен с правильностью определения координат и тогда в базу должны заноситься уже новые координаты перемещенного балуна.

Как их получить?

Что нужно добавить в этот код:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),

        // Создаем геообъект с типом геометрии "Точка".
        myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
            // Описание геометрии.
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [55.754755, 37.596219]
            },
            // Свойства.
            properties: {
                // Контент метки.
                iconContent: 'Move me',
                hintContent: 'marker'
            }
        }, {
            // Опции.
            // Иконка метки будет растягиваться под размер ее содержимого.
            preset: 'islands#blackStretchyIcon',
            // Метку можно перемещать.
            draggable: true
        });

    myMap.geoObjects
        .add(myGeoObject)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчике события завершения перетаскивания (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/#GeoObject__events-summary ) получаем геометрию геообъекта (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/#field_detail__geometry ) и координаты точки (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/IPointGeometryAccess-docpage/#method_detail__getCoordinates ).

Насчет сохранения в базе - вроде бы по условиям использования API Яндекс.Карт нельзя сохранять данные, полученные средствами API (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/ ). Этот вопрос лучше у техподдержки уточнить.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
      center: [55.76, 37.64],
      zoom: 10
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),

    // Создаем геообъект с типом геометрии "Точка".
    myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
      // Описание геометрии.
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [55.754755, 37.596219]
      },
      // Свойства.
      properties: {
        // Контент метки.
        iconContent: 'Move me',
        hintContent: 'marker'
      }
    }, {
      // Опции.
      // Иконка метки будет растягиваться под размер ее содержимого.
      preset: 'islands#blackStretchyIcon',
      // Метку можно перемещать.
      draggable: true
    });
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
  myGeoObject.events.add('dragend', function(e) {
    console.log(myGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates());
  });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Добавление метки на карту</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=<ваш API-ключ>" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```